# Display dates from list that are of current or future months

Tags: php, date, strtotime

With PHP, I wish to loop through a list of dates and only print those that fit the current or a future month. E.g.

Feb 2015
Mar 2015
Apr 2015

The dates are formated as "15 January 2015". I assume strtotime is the best approach? Not sure how to use it though. Any direction is much appreciated.

Comment: *current or a future month*, January is not the current or a future month. I don't understand your example. How is presented the list of dates?

Comment: strtotime is the easiest approach indeed. But keep in mind that it is also the slowest for every date passed to strtotime needs to be parsed.

strtotime() returns a typical unix timestamp of the type integer.

time() also return a typical unix timestamp (also int) of the current time

Comment: A.L. - And I wrote that exactly below the list... But never mind.

Comment: serjoscha - Ok, that's alright though. There's not a lot of scripts running on the page. How would you go about to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this_year = date('Y');
$this_month = date('m');    //month in numeric
$year_to_check = date('Y',strtotime($date_to_check));
$month_to_check = date('m',strtotime($date_to_check));

//check if the $this_year is the same or greater than $year_to_check before checking if the months are the same or different

if($year_to_check < $this_year){ //the year is past
   //do not print
 }else if($year == $year_to_check){  //it's either the same year or a future year 
   //check if the month is less
   if($month_to_check < $this_month){
        //the month is past
    }else{
      //the months are the same or $month_to_check is in the future
   }
 }else if($year_to_check > $this_year){
   //the month is in the future because the $year_to_check is in the future
 }
```

Comment: I like the idea, couldn't get it to work though with my date format ('15 January 2015'). What format is this assuming?

Comment: use mktime() to convert the date to timestamp.

Comment: Like this? $sample = mktime('15 January 2015'); If I apply $month = date('m',strtotime($sample)); I don't get any result.

Comment: Please use google/php manual to find the right syntax for those functions! Once you convert those dates to timestamp the rest of the code should work right!

Answer (score 1):

This function will covert all dates to timestamps and compare them to see if your date is in between.

```
function checkMyDate($date){
  //set TimeZone
  date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
  //create current timestamp
  $d = new DateTime('now');
  //create timestamp from first of the month
  $d->modify('first day of this month');
  $start = $d->getTimestamp();
  //create timestamp from last day of next month
  $d->modify('last day of next month');
  $end = $d->getTimestamp();
  //convert date to timestamp
  $date = strtotime($date);
  echo $start."-".$end."-".$date;
  //check if $date is between $start and $end
  if($date >= $start && $date <= $end){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```